How do I make the range-input for the first circle to be the same as the second circle?
I am creating a price range slider, and I'm having troubles on how to fix this issue:
Price Range Slider.
The first circle should be on the front together with the second circle.
I was expecting it to be like this:
Reference


const rangeValue = document.querySelector(".slider-container .price-slider");

const rangeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".range-input input");
const minRangeInput = rangeInputs[0];
const maxRangeInput = rangeInputs[1];
const priceGap = 500;

function updateSlider() {
  let minValue = parseInt(minRangeInput.value);
  let maxValue = parseInt(maxRangeInput.value);

  if (maxValue - minValue < priceGap) {
    if (minRangeInput === event.target) {
      minRangeInput.value = maxValue - priceGap;
    } else {
      maxRangeInput.value = minValue + priceGap;
    }
  } else {
    const sliderMax = parseInt(minRangeInput.max);
    rangeValue.style.left = (minValue / sliderMax) * 100 + "%";
    rangeValue.style.right = 100 - (maxValue / sliderMax) * 100 + "%";
  }
}

// Event listeners for range inputs
minRangeInput.addEventListener("input", updateSlider);
maxRangeInput.addEventListener("input", updateSlider);
<!-- Range Slider Container -->

<div class="slider-container position-relative mt-3" style="height: 6px; background: #e4e4e4; border-radius: 5px;">
  <!-- Green fill for selected range -->
  <div class="price-slider position-absolute" style="height: 100%; background: #01940b; border-radius: 5px; left: 25%; right: 15%;">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Range Inputs (Two overlapping sliders) -->
<div class="range-input">
  <input type="range" class="form-range min-range" step="50" min="0" max="10000" value="2500" style="position: absolute; pointer-events: none; width: 100%;">
  <input type="range" class="form-range max-range" step="50" min="0" max="10000" value="7500" style="position: absolute; width: 100%;">
</div>




This question is similar to: HTML slider with two inputs possible?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
